# Idea's for making a workbench type interface

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm looking at MeVisLab's interface for generating views of data and I find that that way of viewing control structures is extremely intuitive.

[image: MeVisLab]

It is especially the connected boxes I'm liking, is there any kind of framework that supplies this sort of interface. I know it can be done using Qt but beleave it takes ALOT of work.

Does anyone know of frameworks for making this type of gui?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not c++, but i think it covers your problem, so i would suggest [WireIt](http://neyric.github.com/wireit/index.html).

Examples:

- http://neyric.github.com/wireit/plugins/editor/examples/logicGates/index.html
- http://neyric.github.com/wireit/plugins/composable/examples/jsBox/jsBox.html

It is a Java Script library, so the browser would be your GUI. But i really think, that using the browser is a good thing to do. Learning HTML, CSS and Java Script is about as difficult as learning a new GUI framework. You could concentrate on HTML5 and ignore old browsers and maybe use a nice lib like jQuery, which is like the boost of js. Even if your GUI would only work on Firefox you would still support more platforms than most GUI-Toolkits.

You would of course have to embed a small http-server in your c++ code, you could use [libmicrohttpd](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd/) or [mongoose](https://code.google.com/p/mongoose/) for that.

In the end you have used tools that are very reusable and will have a broader applicability than GUI Frameworks.